# Web Scraping with Puppeteer + Next.js and Express

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, puppeteer, next.js

Trying to find out why my scrape function runs twice. I am trying to create a SSR app that hits a website and scrapes the data. It does work and correctly grabs the data I need but I set headless to false and I can see the browser opening correctly and then opening again and searching for the term `[object Object]`...

I need it to only run on the server that is why I have gone the express + next.js combo.

server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const next = require("next");
const scraper = require("./utils/scraper");

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const nextApp = next({ dev });
const nextHandle = nextApp.getRequestHandler();

nextApp.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express();

  server.get("/search/:query", async (req, res) => {
    const { query } = req.params;

    const listings = await scraper.scrape(query);

    return nextApp.render(req, res, "/search", { search: query, listings });
  });

  server.get("*", (req, res) => {
    return nextHandle(req, res);
  });

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
});
```

scraper.js

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const scrape = async term => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(`https://...&query=${term}`);

  const scrapedData = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const items = document.querySelectorAll(".results");
    return Array.from(items).map(listing => {
      return { ... build up my obj here };
    });
  });

  await browser.close();
  return scrapedData;
};

module.exports.scrape = scrape;
```

Search.jsx (the next.js page)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class extends Component {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    return {
      search: ctx.query.search,
      listings: ctx.query.listings
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { search, listings } = this.props;
    console.log(listings, "client");
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{search} search!</h1>
        { ...listings.map() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 1**
I noticed that puppeteer will correctly only open once if I do not pass my `listings` array into the `nextApp.render` and just log out the results on the server. But as soon as I pass it along to the page to to `getInitialProps` I experience the double loading as explained above.

Comment: why dont just use  `server.get("/search/:query", async (req, res) => {` and then just `const scraped = await scraper.scrape(query)` or `scraper.scrape(query).then(....)` ?

Comment: I updated my code with your simplified recommendations. No difference.

Comment: what you get  if you `console.log(query )` just before `const listings = await scraper.scrape(query);`

Comment: The first run is my query by then like I said it runs the browser again with the string `[object Object]` I noticed that if I do not pass the listings results to `nextApp.render` then it works normally and runs only once... But obviously I need the results passed to the component.